# Nuget package incompatibility and missing namespaces after Windows restore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, syncfusion

My computer recently decided to die on me, so after various other methods of resuscitation failed, I decided to restore to one of Window's automatic backups. The backup was before I had installed Syncfusion Blazor, but at that point in time I was not facing the errors I am currently having. When I loaded up my project in VS, the Error List quickly filled up with messages like:

> Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components 3.1.4 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components 3.1.4 does not support any target frameworks

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddDbContext' and no accessible extension method 'AddDbContext' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

> The type or namespace name 'Syncfusion' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Since I am running the same code as before I'm not sure what is causing these errors. I've tried repairing VS, uninstalling and reinstalling packages, and the "Restore Nuget Packages" option. Intellisense is of no help either, unfortunately.

**Edit:** Here is my `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using ThinBlueLieB.Identity;
using ThinBlueLieB.Data;
using DataAccessLibrary.DataAccess;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;
using Syncfusion.Blazor; //error- count not be found
using ThinBlueLieB.Helper;

namespace ThinBlueLieB
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options => //error no definition
                options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("UserDB"), MySqlOptions => MySqlOptions
                .ServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 18), ServerType.MySql)));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => //error no definition
           options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>();

            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
            services.AddScoped<ISearches, Searches>();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IDataAccess, DataAccess>();            

            services.AddSyncfusionBlazor(); //error - no definition
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        { //error-no definition
            Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("MzA2NDMyQDMxMzgyZTMyMmUzMFVGc2cvTmU0d0NMbWZiRjBkZEl2WGlzU3lHdnBIcTNYRHYzYk5OSHRFTDA9");

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage(); //error- no definition
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you could try to delete the csporj file's Syncfusion.Blazor package reference and restart the computer and install the different version of Syncfusion.Blazor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling Visual Studio, deleting all packages, and messing around in CLI, I found a fix. While I'm not sure this will work for everybody who encounters this issue, all I did was comment, build, and uncomment all the `<PackageReference/>` tags in the csproj file. For others facing the same problem, if that doesn't work for you try:

- [Restoring packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages#when-to-reinstall-a-package)
- [Repairing Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)
- After fixing my issue I got a notification saying that the previous csproj and the current one were encoded differently, so maybe make sure your encoding matches. For me, after fixing it, it became UTF-8 instead of Western European (Windows)